# ¿como generar alertas de vencimiento de fechas? .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Buen día,

Antes que nada estoy empezando a trabajar con .Net Core 3.1 por lo que mi pregunta puede resultar un tanto sencilla para algunos, pero en mi caso no se como hacerlo.

La pregunta es como puedo generar una alerta si tengo una fecha por ejemplo 31/12/2020 00:00 y necesito que 10 días antes o N días me genere una alerta de vencimiento de la fecha.

Algunos me dirán con javascript pero no se tampoco como pasar y recibir parámetros en javascript desde .net, o si se puede realizar con un método directamente en el modelo como lo podría pintar en el navegador o en la vista.

La idea es que en el navegador al cargar el index aparezca la alerta de esa fecha algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero haberme hecho entender, gracias por la ayuda de antemano.

Comment: Si tienes la fecha en la vista en puro JavaScript: puedes realizar una diferencia de la fecha de hoy con la fecha que tiene y si la cantidad de días cumple con tu regla de negocio, emites la alerta. Podrías utilizar javascript puro o usar la librería moment.js

Comment: Cómo puedo enviar el campo fecha a javascript para retornar la alerta?

Comment: Hay múltiples maneras y eso deja a tu pregunta como demasiado amplia y/o basada en opiniones, ergo, potencialmente podría ser cerrada. Si deseas una respuesta lo más exacta posible, coloca en tu pregunta todo el código que tienes, lo que has intentado, aquí unas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Las fechas en .Net tienen una serie de métodos que te pueden servir como `AddDays` así, por ejemplo si quieres saber si una fecha está en el intervalo de n días hasta hoy puedes utilizar (escribo de memoria):

```
bool MustShowAlert(DateTime date, int interval)
{
     return date.AddDays(interval) >= DateTime.Now()
}
```

Donde `date` es la fecha e `interval` es el número de días.